# Need to build a request object based on type.How would you do it?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am confused about which pattern to use/best for my requirement.I hope you can clarify. Not sure if to use a builder or factory.

The scenario is this . 
Create a request object and pass it to a third party component that I have no control over

Request can be of many types -- EmployeeRequest-WorkerRequest-etc... and each request will have methods like "GetXXX" -GetYYY" etc..

Noddy example
I have done as follows:

```
        class Program
            {
                static void Main()
                {
                    Request employeeRequest = new EmployeeRequest { Id=1,FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar" };

                    Service myservice=new Service();
                    var response = myservice.DoSomething(employeeRequest);

                    //do something with the response ...
                }
            }

            public class Service
            {
                public Response DoSomething(Request request)
                {
                    Factory factory = new Factory();
                    Request myRequest = factory.Create(request);

                    //Call my third party component
                    //Response myResponse = MyThirdPartyComponent.DoSomething(myRequest);
                    //return myResponse;
                    return new Response();
                }
            }

            public class Factory
            {
                public Request Create(Request request)
                {
                    if (request is EmployeeRequest)
                    {
                        EmployeeRequest employeeRequest = new EmployeeRequest();
                        employeeRequest.FirstName = request.FirstName;
                        employeeRequest.LastName = request.LastName;
                        return employeeRequest;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        WorkerRequest workerRequest = new WorkerRequest();
                        workerRequest.FirstName = request.FirstName;
                        workerRequest.LastName = request.LastName;
                        return workerRequest;
                    }
                }
            }

            public abstract class Request
            {
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public string FirstName { get; set; }
                public string LastName { get; set; }
            }
            public class Response
            {
                public string FirstName { get; set; }
                public string LastName { get; set; }
            }

            public class EmployeeRequest : Request
            {}
            public class WorkerRequest : Request
            {}
            public class EmployeeResponse : Response
            {}
            public class WorkerResponse : Response
            {}
```

If you were to implement it how would you do it:

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to fill out properties of the `Request` base type for types that inherit `Request`, make a generic method (you might need to change your model a little):

```
void Main()
{
    var request = new WorkRequest();
    request.FirstName = "joe";
    request.LastName ="smith";

    var employeeRequest = RequestFactory.Create<EmployeeRequest>(request);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(employeeRequest.FirstName == request.FirstName);
}

public class RequestFactory
{
    public static T Create<T>(Request request)
        where T : Request, new()
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), request);
    }
}

public abstract class Request
{
    protected Request() {}

    protected Request(Request request)
    {
        this.FirstName = request.FirstName;
        this.LastName = request.LastName;
    }

    public string FirstName {get;set;}

    public string LastName {get;set;}
}

public class EmployeeRequest : Request
{
    public EmployeeRequest(){}

    public EmployeeRequest(Request request) 
        : base(request)
    {

    }
}   

public class WorkRequest : Request
{
    public WorkRequest(){}

    public WorkRequest(Request request) 
        : base(request)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.My problem is that at the time of creating the factory i need to determine the type,and this is what I would like to improve EG.if (request is EmployeeRequest){ var employeeRequest = RequestFactory.Create<EmployeeRequest>(request);} if (request is WorkerRequest){ var workerRequest= RequestFactory.Create<WorkerRequest>(request); How can I improve this?thanks

Comment: The simplest way would be to make your service's method signatures more explicit. Service.DoEmployeeSomething() and Service.DoWorkerSomething() vs just Service.DoSomething()

Answer (score 0):

I would personally, instead of having `Factory` to build my request, probabbly add abstract method Request `GetRequest()` to `Request` abstract class, and implement its concrete implementation in every `EmployeeRequest`, `WorkerRequest`,....

Cause, basically, at least looking at code provided, what you do is:

1. Create `EmployerRequest`and assign it to `Request`
2. After pass it to `Factory`'s method to make `is` and create `EmployerRequest` "clone" to pass to server. Don't really know if you really need that, but assuming that yes, at this point, why just don't ask the *object itself* create another type of *itself*?

Hope that was clear my opinion.

Regards.